# Automate amazon rds snapshots from heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, rake, snapshot, amazon-rds

I'm using amazon rds with a heroku app and would like to automate daily snapshots. My intention is to schedule a rake task that will perform the snapshot. How can I perform an amazon rds snapshot from ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No dice yet but this is pretty close:

```
# Gemfile
source :rubygems

gem 'amazon-ec2'
gem 'rake'


# Rakefile
require 'rubygems'
require 'rake'
require 'AWS'

desc 'create snapshot'
task 'create_snapshot' do
  @rds = AWS::RDS::Base.new(:access_key_id => ACCESS_KEY_ID, 
                            :secret_access_key => SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
  @rds.create_db_snapshot :db_snapshot_identifier => 'snapshot name',
                          :db_instance_identifier => 'db name'
end
```

Only problem is I get the error:

```
Unsupported digest algorithm (sha256).
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly in Rails 3 rake task. I didn't get any errors.